# Multiple download links to one zip file before download javascript

Tags: javascript, url, download, jszip

Is it possible, in javascript, to have multiple download urls sent into one zip file and that zip file can be downloaded. So pretty much, on my web page, there is one button, that when clicked downloads a zip file of all the files from the download urls compressed into the zip?

I believe I'd need to use jszip or some tool like that. Is this at all possible and is there any advice on where to start?

Comment: zip target files at **server side** and return url after click, then do download via this url

Comment: What do you mean by "multiple download urls"?

Comment: @YinGang but lets say I already have the download links for the files stored in an array. How would i zip those so the user can download the ziped file only?

Comment: **Ajax** the stored array to server side --> server **zip** files --> return zip url --> request url to download.

Comment: All of the files are at same domain at server?

Comment: @gang how would i do those first two steps?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `JSZip.js`, `XMLHttpRequest()`, `Array.prototype.map()` , `Promise.all()` to create `.zip` file when all requests for files have completed; use `<a>` element with `download` attribute set to `objectURL` of `.zip` file at `JSZip` `.generateAsync()` function, click on `a` element should display `Save File` dialog with created `.zip` as downloadable file.

```
<head>
  <script src="jszip.js"></script>
  <script>
    window.onload = function() {
      var zip = new JSZip();
      var a = document.querySelector("a");
      var urls = ["a.html", "b.html"];

      function request(url) {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
          var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
          httpRequest.open("GET", url);
          httpRequest.onload = function() {
            zip.file(url, this.responseText);
            resolve()
          }
          httpRequest.send()
        })
      }

      Promise.all(urls.map(function(url) {
          return request(url)
        }))
        .then(function() {
          console.log(zip);
          zip.generateAsync({
              type: "blob"
          })
          .then(function(content) {
            a.download = "folder" + new Date().getTime();
            a.href = URL.createObjectURL(content);
            a.innerHTML = "download " + a.download;
          });
        })
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a href="" download>download</a>
</body>
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/baPtkILg927DtJfh4b5Y?p=preview

Comment: That doesn't work for urls needed to be downloaded. That only works if you have the html files in the same folder. Suppose I have this download link: https:\/\/www.youtubeinmp3.com\/download\/get\/?i=trShzDCP0ESQ5bFdcMpe8y6H6WJvxYLXMa7OtmJMeO%2BfxY1E1Rx5FQwsWk%2BDS9fEoIXCo8QboB0dX6%2FP0e2rJw%3D%3D
I want one button that when clicked will put these downloads into one zipped folder. When I change a.html to the link I provided, it no longer works.

Comment: @Dude1310  _"When I change a.html to the link I provided, it no longer works. "_  The URL does not have `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header set _"`XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/?video=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`"_

Comment: Yes but there are ways to work around that, for example downloading this chrome extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

and even after I download that, replacing a.html with the download link for the mp3 file I provided won't work because it gives an error stating that they could not find the location of the mp3 file because your code only downloads files that you have saved already, I'm trying to put a downloaded file from the internet into a zip folder.

Comment: @Dude1310 _"with the download link for the mp3 file I provided won't work because it gives an error stating that they could not find the location of the mp3 file"_ Not certain where `.mp3` actual location is? The "Download" window appears to be an `<iframe>` that when clicked opens an ad? _"I'm trying to put a downloaded file from the internet into a zip folder"_ Yes, what is the URL of the actual resource, `.mp3` file, that you want to download?

Comment: If you press this link: https:\/\/www.youtubeinmp3.com\/download\/get\/?i=trShzDCP0ESQ5bFdcMpe8y6H6WJvxYLXMa7OtmJMeO%2FqhE5HNe6etvXNYLqsXm5HkScdBuZ%2BJgrHtb%2FWohCaWg%3D%3D

a download will start right away for an mp3 file. Instead of downloading that mp3 file, i want to put it into a zip with other mp3 files for download. i'm using an api to get the mp3 files from youtube. Try going to that link^

Comment: @Dude1310 _"No Video Was Found"_ You probably could unescape URL?  How would link at another page  be clicked using `XMLHttpRequest()`? What is the direct link to resource? _" i'm using an api to get the mp3 files from youtube"_ Link to API documentation? Or is only approach available clicking download link at page?

Comment: Oh sorry, I guess the url is relative. I'm using the api from this website: https://www.youtubeinmp3.com/api/

try using the json link if you scroll down: www.youtubeinmp3.com/fetch/?format=JSON&video=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i62Zjga8JOM

this returns a link for download to an mp3 file that I want to put in a zipped folder.

Comment: @Dude1310 `XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.youtubeinmp3.com/download/get/?i=Hes1wwZTx03diwb8wuslSc9mm49DGyGQYnbaQZoJuNdlQ6Ago%2BN4LvUUQA5qBs43gzh1APL5HkzCAquh%2Fzceaw%3D%3D. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: So is it impossible? or could you download this chrome extension to make it work: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en

Comment: That's really confusing. But for example, trying a different download link with your code, such as replacing "a.html" with "https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/05/05/02/15/gecko-1373144_640.jpg?attachment", the code still doesnt work.

Comment: Same result `XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://pixabay.com/static/uploads/photo/2016/05/05/02/15/gecko-1373144_640.jpg?attachment%22. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://stackoverflow.com' is therefore not allowed access.`

Comment: Are there any download links for anything that you can find that actually work?

Comment: Have you tried link, above? See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143093/origin-is-not-allowed-by-access-control-allow-origin

Comment: @Dude1310 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176397/multiple-download-links-to-one-zip-file-before-download-javascript/37176830?noredirect=1#comment61910769_37176830; see also linked page at previous comment

Comment: Thanks for all the help haha but still confused a bit. Why can't I use the chrome extension to override the error?

Comment: @Dude1310 Perhaps take the time to read all of the possible solutions at linked stackoverflow page? And links from that page http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3102819/disable-same-origin-policy-in-chrome

Answer (score 2):

I recently had to solve the same issue and had found a solution using [JSZipUtils](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip-utils).

The solution can be found here http://plnkr.co/edit/vWARo0dXbkgzmjyoRNi0?p=preview

I have two files that I would like to zip and download via the users browser and I call the function `getBinaryContent(path, callback)` on both files. The path here is the where the file is stored.

The two files are a .wav file and a .json file. Each of them should be treated differenly and hence you should use `{base64:true,binary:true}` for the .wav file and `{binary:true}` for the json file as an argument for the function file of [JSZip](https://github.com/Stuk/jszip).

The code can be found here as well

```
var file_confirmation=[false,false];
var file_name=["test1.wav","test.json"];
var urlList =["test.wav","test.json"];

var filenameSave ="myZip";


function zipFiles(id,urls)
{
    zip = new JSZip();

JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(urls[0],function (err, data) 
{
    if(!err)
    {
        var dic={base64:true,binary:true}; //WAV File Encoding
        zip.file(file_name[0], data, dic);
        file_confirmation[0]=true;
        downloadZipIfAllReady(id);
    }
});

JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(urls[1],function (err, data) 
    {
        if(!err)
        {
            var dic={binary:true}; //JSON File Encoding
            zip.file(file_name[1], data, dic);
            file_confirmation[1]=true;
            downloadZipIfAllReady(id);
        }
    });
}    

function downloadZipIfAllReady(id)
    {
        if(file_confirmation.every(function(element, index, array) {return element;}))
        {
             zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
                .then(function(content)
                {
                  var a = document.querySelector("#"+id);
                  a.download = filenameSave;
                  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(content);
                  a.click();
            });
    }
}


$(document).ready(function()
{

 zipFiles("a_id",urlList);

})
```

Comment: when i download your example as a zip file and run the index file off my computer nothing happens, would you know of any reason for this? https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k4e3s79xp6fsap/Screenshot%202017-01-15%2016.55.20.png?dl=0

Comment: I would say debug the Javascript zipFiles method and see what is wrong.

Comment: The problem is your accessing the link with file://: ..  You should instead install a local server (like XAMPP) and open locally using localhost/..../index.html and then the cross origin error will disappear