# How to export a full HTML5 and JS app as a download?

Tags: javascript, android, html, mobile, export

I created an app (for mobile devices) and it's 100% HTML5 and JS.
I didn't use anything like Java or another native coding language.
Of course I can put the app on the internet and access them like a website.
But I want to get the app exported as a download, like it's an app you get from the playstore.
It must be downloadable because it should be usable without an internet connection.

I created the app by just typing the HTML and javascript files.
Should I zip them together, or put them in one folder, and just download it on the device? And then create a webpage where the app can be downloaded?

Comment: You can try reactNative to run it on mobile devices and electron to make it run on desktop: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/ and electron: http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Yes, you can provide the folder as a `.zip` download see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176397/multiple-download-links-to-one-zip-file-before-download-javascript.

Comment: This is not an Android question.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using Phonegap (http://phonegap.com/) or Apache Cordova (https://cordova.apache.org/) to translate your non-native code into an app.

Answer (score 0):

It's not feasible to build your own APK by hand; it's definitely *not* as simple as zipping up the HTML and JS and putting it on the Google Play Store.

One option, as already mentioned, would be to use Phonegap or a similar framework. Another option would be create an app that just displays your HTML/JS in a WebView. There are some decent tutorials out there on how to do that, one that I just glanced at was https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/gettingstarted - you can find a lot more on Google.

In terms of deployment, it's definitely possible to put it up on your own server and have people download it from there and side-load it (or even to manually distribute it somehow) but I don't recommend either option unless you have a good reason to because it can make distributing updates very painful (especially if you're attempting manual deployment). (It can be very difficult for users to know when there's an upgrade available, for example, or to track which version of your software they're on).

Comment: _"It's not feasible to build your own APK by hand"_?