# Extract uploaded file using adm zip

Tags: javascript, node.js, filereader, adm-zip

I am trying to get the list of files in a uploaded file using adm-zip. As we cant get the path of the uploaded file , iam trying to convert the zip into a Buffer and pass it to the adm-zip. But `zip.getEntries();` its not giving me the list of files.

```
 checkZipFiles(){
      var AdmZip = require("adm-zip");
      var filesInput =  document.querySelector('input[type="file"]').files[0];
      var res;
      var zip = new AdmZip(filesInput);
      console.log(' zip is '+JSON.stringify(zip));
      var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
      console.log(' zipEntries is '+zipEntries);
      zipEntries.forEach(function(zipEntry) {
          console.log(zipEntry.toString()); // outputs zip entries information
          if (zipEntry.entryName == "my_file.txt") {
               console.log(zipEntry.data.toString('utf8')); 
          }
      });
      var reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsArrayBuffer(filesInput);
      var bytes,buf ;
      reader.onloadend = function(e){
          var readLen=e.target.result.byteLength;
          var arrayBuffer = reader.result
           bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
          console.log('insidebytes is '+bytes);
           buf = new Buffer(e.target.result.byteLength);
           for (var i = 0; i < buf.length; ++i) {
            buf[i] = bytes[i];
        }
          console.log(e.target.result.byteLength+' length is '+bytes.byteLength);
          var myZip = e.target.result;   
          console.log('bytes is '+bytes);
          console.log('buf is '+buf);

            zip = new AdmZip(buf);
//            console.log(zip+' reader ');
            var zipEntries = zip.getEntries();
            console.log(' zip is '+zipEntries);  

      }

  }
```

When i print the buffer it prints something like below , with the file name inside the zip.

121832 length is 121832

}+����Y���L�]��%:�*���`_����ld� ��c{\��h7��`�L��e33�\"ԅտ׉��v�˕3�-��^�'�Ҁ霗�^�p�q�W��������vްR�����akny���Egr����G�%1/���Wer����\d���A�upR�L����up�jemF���� ��k9y�*�^Ն;h�1:ca delete.txt
�-�-F1p[

But AdmZip gives below error. Is the issue with the buffer or AdmZip not able to read the buffer?

```
Uncaught Invalid END header (bad signature) mainHeader.js?4281:35
```

Comment: Not certain what issue is?

Comment: var zipEntries = zip.getEntries(); Should give the files in ZIP. its not giving

Comment: Why do you call `JSON.stringify()` on `File` objects?

Comment: empty array.. [ ]. I think i am not passing the correct input to   zip = new AdmZip(myZip);

Comment: What does `console.log(zipEntries)` log?

Comment: It doesnt print anyhing.. Thats the reason i have put stringify.. which prints empty array.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37176397/multiple-download-links-to-one-zip-file-before-download-javascript/

Comment: I cant use JSZip as adm-zip is only on the allowed modules ..